# plotting using modified array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

```
clear

for I = 1:1:41
    Result(I) = sqrt((I-1)*5+20)
end
plot(result)
```

The above is an example from my lab book. I want to do the same kind of thing except plotting the graph 4x^2-3x+2 where x is from 0 to 10 in steps of 0.5.
it doesn't seem to work when i substitute x for I though?
could someone help me out?

Comment: Seems like a homework, please add the homework tag if it is.

Comment: @Luke Gilling, take a look at the example in the provided answer.  The key takehome is the way in which you generate the array that you desire.  Be careful with mathematical operations on the elements. Note in the answer that `.^` is used instead of `^`.  There are similar operators for multiplication and divide, all of which operate on the arrays / matrices point-wise--which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=0:0.5:10;
plot(x, 4*x.^2-3*x+2);
```